# What's after Z in SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS?

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I am trying to prove a table design flaw in a production db, that a table must not have a clustered primary key on a column that can have a random data, in this case a code keyed in by end user.

Though we know the solution is to make the PK as non-clustered, I still need to add rows to it for testing purpose on its replica. Therefore, I will need to know what would be the character I can use after 'Z' as a prefix.

More, the column is not a unicode, and it would be a mess to prefix my fake data with a series of Zs. The table is now having hundred-thousands rows, and each insertion is taking seconds.

Comment: This is not working as the collation will pull this before 'A': select char(ascii('z') + 1)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just run this and go down the list.  I added the sandwiching dots for clarity, esp. when non-visible characters are involved.

```
select number, '.' + char(number) + '.' collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS thechar
from master..spt_values
where type='p' and number between 28 and 255
order by thechar
```

There are only 4 characters coming after 'Z', since you say the column is not N(Var)Char.

```
121 .y.
89  .Y.
253 .ý.
221 .Ý.
255 .ÿ.
90  .Z.
122 .z.
208 .Ð.
240 .ð.
254 .þ.
222 .Þ.
```

Comment: Thanks Richard, unfortunately, .Ð.ð.þ.Þ. had been auto translated into .D.d.t.T., this is because (sorry) the collation was actually Chinese_PRC_CI_AS, and there's nothing beyond Z! BTW, nice logic with 2048 free number by master..spt_values.